# How to embed subtitles into an mp4 file using gstreamer

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg, gstreamer, mp4

### My Goal

I'm trying to embed subtitles into an mp4 file using the `mp4mux` gstreamer element.

### What I've tried

The pipeline I would like to use is:

```
GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=sample-nosub-avc.mp4 ! qtdemux ! queue ! video/x-h264 ! mp4mux name=mux reserved-moov-update-period=1000 ! filesink location=output.mp4 filesrc location=english.srt ! subparse ! queue ! text/x-raw,format=utf8 ! mux.subtitle_0
```

It just demuxes a sample mp4 file for the h.264 stream and then muxes it together with an srt subtitle file.

The error I get is:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
0:00:00.009958915 1324869 0x5624a8c7a0a0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3600:gst_base_src_start_complete:<filesrc0> pad not activated yet
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
0:00:00.010128080 1324869 0x5624a8c53de0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3072:gst_base_src_loop:<filesrc1> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:00.010129102 1324869 0x5624a8c53e40 WARN                 qtdemux qtdemux_types.c:239:qtdemux_type_get: unknown QuickTime node type pasp
0:00:00.010140810 1324869 0x5624a8c53de0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3072:gst_base_src_loop:<filesrc1> error: streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
0:00:00.010172990 1324869 0x5624a8c53e40 WARN                 qtdemux qtdemux.c:3237:qtdemux_parse_trex:<qtdemux0> failed to find fragment defaults for stream 1
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc1: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(3072): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc1:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

### My Thoughts

I believe the issue is not related to the above warning but rather `mp4mux`'s incompatibility with srt subtitles.

The reason I belive this is because, other debug logs hint at it, but also stealing the subititles from another mp4 file and muxing it back together *does* work.

```
gst-launch-1.0  filesrc location=sample-nosub-avc.mp4 ! qtdemux ! mp4mux name=mux ! filesink location=output.mp4 filesrc location=sample-with-subs.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux demux.subtitle_1 ! text/x-raw,format=utf8 ! queue ! mux.subtitle_0
```

A major catch 22 I am having is that mp4 files don't typically support srt subtitles, but gstreamer's `subparse` element doesn't support parsing mp4 subtitle formats (tx3g, ttxt, etc.) so I'm not sure how I'm meant to put it all together.

I'm very sorry for the lengthy question but I've tried many things so it was difficult to condense it. Any hints or help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Just some extra information:
I need to be able to remove the subtitles eventually so elements like `textoverlay` and `subtitleoverlay` won't work since they add the subtitles to the video stream (rather than creating a separate mp4 meta data atom like mp4mux).

Comment: Using a 3rd party program such as ffmpeg or mp4box is a possibility and I've confirmed it accomplishes my goal. However, if possible I'd like to use gstreamer.